# Moving object stutters using delta time to unify speed

Tags: c++, opengl

I have tried different machines, VSync on and off.

I have provided my main method and display method. In the main look I calculate delta using GLFWs GetTime method.

If I explicitly set deltaTime = 0.016 to lock the target speed, the triangle moves smoothly.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /*
        INIT AND OTHER STUFF SNIPPED OUT
    */

    double currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
    double lastFrame = currentFrame;
    double deltaTime;

    double a=0;
    double speed = 0.6;
    //Main loop
    while(true)
    {
        a++;

        currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        /** I know that delta time is around 0.016 at my framerate **/
        //deltaTime = 0.016;

        x = sin( a * deltaTime * speed ) * 0.8f;
        y = cos( a * deltaTime * speed ) * 0.8f;

        display();

        if(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) || !glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED))
            break;
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(playerProgram);

        glUniform3f(playerLocationUniform,x,y,z);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, playerVertexBufferObject);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glUseProgram(0);
    glfwSwapBuffers();

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `deltaTime` as if it was a global framerate and calculating the sine and cosine based on a frame number (`a`) multiplied by that rate.  What that means is a minor fluctuation in `deltaTime` between frames will cause larger changes in position as `a` becomes larger.

In the other case, where you set a constant `deltaTime`, you still get small glitches when a frame is rendered at the wrong time.

What you actually need to do is this:

```
#define TAU (M_PI * 2.0)

    currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
    deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
    lastFrame = currentFrame;

    a += deltaTime * speed;

    // Optional, keep the cycle bounded to reduce precision errors
    // if you plan to leave this running for a long time...
    if( a > TAU ) a -= TAU;

    x = sin( a ) * 0.8f;
    y = cos( a ) * 0.8f;
```

Comment: Thanks that looks to be working nicely. Could you Explain "In the other case, where you set a constant deltaTime, you still get small glitches when a frame is rendered at the wrong time." please, I don't understand what you mean there.

Comment: @Andy : if you are incrementing the frame count every cycle and assuming a constant frame rate, and then for some reason one frame is rendered late you are not compensating for that late frame: *eg* it might be frame 47, but you don't draw until frame 47.5.  With smooth motion, the human eye can pick up on this, because it is already predicting where the object will be.  If a delayed frame doesn't delay future frames this is okay (and it's only a small, temporary motion glitch), but if it causes all future frames to be out by 0.5 the problem can compound and will lead to dropped frames.